# Mb_stripos и пробел

Tags: php

Есть строки, например, "Шуба" и "шуба".

Если проверить данные строки с помощью `mb_stripos` (еще пишу `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8")`),
то выдаст false. Если перед проверяемым словом поставить пробел (" Шуба"), то выдает true.

Как сделать так, чтобы пробел был не нужен? Просто, на мой взгляд, вставлять пробел перед строкой - это костыль какой-то.

Comment: Ох ёлки, до меня дошло. Я ведь просто проверял if(mb_stripos(...)), а надо было !== false. Спасибо

Comment: @MrGaliev Вы с [Gearman](http://hashcode.ru/questions/390536/php-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-gearman-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-class-gearmanworker-not-found) разобрались?

Comment: Нет, временно забил на это. Пока нагрузки будут небольшие, буду использовать fastcgi finish request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@MrGaliev](/users/18121/mrgaliev)](/users/18121/mrgaliev) В чём, собственно, проблема? [Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6ac979dc26b0c918dc3b7699db68901388eef05)